# Sidekiq worker processes not updating database records properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sidekiq

I have a sidekiq worker that processes certain series of task in batch. Once it completes the job, it updates a tracker table on the success/failure of the task. Each batch has a unique identifier that is being passed to the worker script and the worker process queries that table for this unique id and update that particular row through a activerecord query similar to:

```
cpr = MODEL.find(tracker_unique_id)

cpr.update_attributes(:attempted => cpr[:attempted] + 1, :success => cpr[:success] + 1)
```

What I have noticed is that the tracker only get record of 1 set of task running even though I can see from the sidekiq log and another result table that x number of tasks finished running.

Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update_attributes call has a race condition as you cannot increment like that safely.  Multiple threads will stomp on each other.  You must do a proper UPDATE SQL statement.

> update models set attempted = attempted + 1 where tracker_unique_id = ?

Comment: Yeah I think this is it,

Comment: I was able to get it working correctly by using this instead
Model.increment_counter(:attempted,cpr[:id])

Comment: Thank you Mike. You are right. Raw sql update works for me: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE messages SET xiaomi_query_ids = xiaomi_query_ids || '{#{query_id}}' WHERE id = #{message.id}")`